# How can I serialize a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, serialization, local-storage

For example, say I have a function defined as follows:

```
function foo() {
  return "Hello, serialized world!";
}
```

I want to be able to serialize that function and store it using `localStorage`. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: why do you want to serialize a function?

Comment: What if the function being serialised references variables/functions in the containing scope? If you deserialise it in the wrong place it won't work...

Comment: Can't speak to Akash's use, but I want to serialize a function to store it as a validation function in CouchDB. The variables passed in and restricted scope are well defined.

Comment: @DanielA.White It really irritates me when this is the first response to somebody's question!

Comment: @DanielA.White yeah, saying "you probably don't want to do this" is usually not as helpful as answering "here's how to do it...and here's why it's probably a bad idea"

Comment: @Andy it could be an x-y problem and im looking for solutions.

Comment: The OP specifically asked how to "serialize that function and store it using localStorage" so trying to speculate about some other solution is off-topic.  It would only be on topic if the OP said "I want to do <something>...I'm trying to accomplish it by storing a function in localStorage"

Comment: People blow off questions they consider bad practice all too often on StackOverflow instead of just objectively answering the question and then adding a word of advice afterwards.  The latter is much more helpful to beginners.

Comment: @Michael you're really fun!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Most browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, possibly others) return the definition of functions from the `.toString()` method:

```
> function foo() { return 42; }
> foo.toString()
"function foo() { return 42; }"
```

Just be careful because native functions won't serialize properly. For example:

```
> alert.toString()
"function alert() { [native code] }"
```

Comment: How would you get the function back from the string?

Comment: @David Wolever - the ES 3 and 5 specs say that Function.prototype.toString returns "[an] implementation-dependent representation of the function" that "has the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration" (§15.3.4.2). Probably worth noting that there is nothing to say that it must be the literal code of the function, it could just be `function foo(){/* returns 42 */}`.

Comment: You might want to note that this won't easily work if the function is a closure.

Comment: @AkashGupta use Function's constructor with return statement

Comment: The function constructor requires the arguments to be passed explicitly. Instead using eval(...) restores them from the toString representation and works with lambdas as well.
Of course it might not be a bulletproof solution for a generic serializer/deserializer but it worked for me much better than the examples in the other answers.

Comment: This also works with es6 loving it.

Answer (score 37):

```js
function foo() {
  alert('native function');
  return 'Hello, serialised world!';
}
```

### Serializing

```js
var storedFunction = foo.toString();
```

### Deserializing

```js
var actualFunction = new Function('return ' + foo.toString())()
```

#### Explanation

foo.toString() will be string version of the function foo

```
"function foo() { ... return 'Hello, serialised world!';}"
```

But `new Function` takes the body of a function and not the function itself.

See [MDN: Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

So we can create a function that returns us back this function and assign it to some variable.

```
"return function foo() { ... return 'Hello, serialised world!';}"
```

So now when we pass this string to the constructor we get a function and we immediately execute it to get back our original function. :)

Comment: or just use `eval(storedFunction)`, which will directly return the function

Answer (score 20):

I made this answer to address some pretty big flaws with the existing answers: `.toString()`/`eval()` and `new Function()` on their own wont work at all if your function uses [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or named arguments (`function (named, arg) {}`), respectively.

Using [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) below, **all you need to do is call [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as usual** on the function, and use `Function.deserialise` when [`parse()`ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter).

The following wont work for concise functions (`hello => 'there'`), but for standard ES5 fat functions it'll return it as it was defined, closures notwithstanding of course. [My other answer will work with all that ES6 goodness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123745/2518317).

---

```js
Function.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var parts = this
        .toString()
        .match(/^\s*function[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{(.*)}\s*$/)
    ;
    if (parts == null)
        throw 'Function form not supported';

    return [
        'window.Function',
        parts[1].trim().split(/\s*,\s*/),
        parts[2]
    ];
};
Function.deserialise = function(key, data) {
    return (data instanceof Array && data[0] == 'window.Function') ?
        new (Function.bind.apply(Function, [Function].concat(data[1], [data[2]]))) :
        data
    ;
};
```

---

Take a look at the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5yh7130z/)

At it's simplest:

```js
var test = function(where) { return 'hello ' + where; };
test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test), Function.deserialise);
console.log(test('there'));
//prints 'hello there'
```

---

More usefully, **you can serialise entire objects containing functions and pull them back out**:

```js
test = {
  a : 2,
  run : function(x, y, z) { return this.a + x + y + z; }
};
var serialised = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log(serialised);
console.log(typeof serialised);

var tester = JSON.parse(serialised, Function.deserialise);
console.log(tester.run(3, 4, 5));
```

Outputs:

```js
{"a":2,"run":["window.Function",["x","y","z"]," return this.a + x + y + z; "]}
string
14
```

---

I didn't test older IE's, but it works on IE11, FF, Chrome, Edge.

<sub>NB, the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) of the function is lost, if you use that property then there's nothing you can do, really.

You can change it to not use `prototype` easily, but that's for you to do if that's what you need.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244123/discussion-on-answer-by-hashbrown-how-can-i-serialize-a-function-in-javascript).

Answer (score 12):

If you needed a way to serialise [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES6 I have written a serialiser that makes everything work.

**All you need to do is call `JSON.stringify()` as usual** on the function or object containing the function, and call `Function.deserialise` on [the other side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) for the magic to work.

<sub>Obviously you shouldn't expect closures to work, it is serialisation after all, but defaults, destructuring, `this`, `arguments`, `class` member functions, it'll all be preserved.

If you're only using ES5 notations please just use [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122739/2518317). This one really is above and beyond</sub>

---

[**Here's the demonstration**](https://codepen.io/Hashbrown/pen/yEZoxj)

Working in Chrome/Firefox/Edge.
Bellow is the output from the demo; a few functions, the serialised string, then calling the new function created after deserialisation.

```js
test = {
    //make the function
    run : function name(x, y, z) { return this.a + x + y + z; },
    a : 2
};
//serialise it, see what it looks like
test = JSON.stringify(test) //{"run":["window.Function",["x","y","z"],"return this.a + x + y + z;"],"a":2}
test = JSON.parse(test, Function.deserialise)
//see if `this` worked, should be 2+3+4+5 : 14
test.run(3, 4, 5) //14

test = () => 7
test = JSON.stringify(test) //["window.Function",[""],"return 7"]
JSON.parse(test, Function.deserialise)() //7

test = material => material.length
test = JSON.stringify(test) //["window.Function",["material"],"return material.length"]
JSON.parse(test, Function.deserialise)([1, 2, 3]) //3

test = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => a + b + c
test = JSON.stringify(test) //["window.Function",["[a, b] = [1, 2]","{ x: c } = { x: a + b }"],"return a + b + c"]
JSON.parse(test, Function.deserialise)([3, 4]) //14

class Bob {
    constructor(bob) { this.bob = bob; }
    //a fat function with no `function` keyword!!
    test() { return this.bob; }
    toJSON() { return {bob:this.bob, test:this.test} }
}
test = new Bob(7);
test.test(); //7
test = JSON.stringify(test); //{"bob":7,"test":["window.Function",[""],"return this.bob;"]}
test = JSON.parse(test, Function.deserialise);
test.test(); //7
```

---

And finally, the magic

```js
Function.deserialise = function(key, data) {
    return (data instanceof Array && data[0] == 'window.Function') ?
        new (Function.bind.apply(Function, [Function].concat(data[1], [data[2]]))) :
        data
    ;
};
Function.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var whitespace = /\s/;
    var pair = /\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/;

    var args = new Array();
    var string = this.toString();

    var fat = (new RegExp(
        '^\s*(' +
        ((this.name) ? this.name + '|' : '') +
        'function' +
        ')[^)]*\\('
    )).test(string);

    var state = 'start';
    var depth = new Array(); 
    var tmp;

    for (var index = 0; index < string.length; ++index) {
        var ch = string[index];

        switch (state) {
        case 'start':
            if (whitespace.test(ch) || (fat && ch != '('))
                continue;

            if (ch == '(') {
                state = 'arg';
                tmp = index + 1;
            }
            else {
                state = 'singleArg';
                tmp = index;
            }
            break;

        case 'arg':
        case 'singleArg':
            var escaped = depth.length > 0 && depth[depth.length - 1] == '\\';
            if (escaped) {
                depth.pop();
                continue;
            }
            if (whitespace.test(ch))
                continue;

            switch (ch) {
            case '\\':
                depth.push(ch);
                break;

            case ']':
            case '}':
            case ')':
                if (depth.length > 0) {
                    if (pair.test(depth[depth.length - 1] + ch))
                        depth.pop();
                    continue;
                }
                if (state == 'singleArg')
                    throw '';
                args.push(string.substring(tmp, index).trim());
                state = (fat) ? 'body' : 'arrow';
                break;

            case ',':
                if (depth.length > 0)
                    continue;
                if (state == 'singleArg')
                    throw '';
                args.push(string.substring(tmp, index).trim());
                tmp = index + 1;
                break;

            case '>':
                if (depth.length > 0)
                    continue;
                if (string[index - 1] != '=')
                    continue;
                if (state == 'arg')
                    throw '';
                args.push(string.substring(tmp, index - 1).trim());
                state = 'body';
                break;

            case '{':
            case '[':
            case '(':
                if (
                    depth.length < 1 ||
                    !(depth[depth.length - 1] == '"' || depth[depth.length - 1] == '\'')
                )
                    depth.push(ch);
                break;

            case '"':
                if (depth.length < 1)
                    depth.push(ch);
                else if (depth[depth.length - 1] == '"')
                    depth.pop();
                break;
            case '\'':
                if (depth.length < 1)
                    depth.push(ch);
                else if (depth[depth.length - 1] == '\'')
                    depth.pop();
                break;
            }
            break;

        case 'arrow':
            if (whitespace.test(ch))
                continue;
            if (ch != '=')
                throw '';
            if (string[++index] != '>')
                throw '';
            state = 'body';
            break;

        case 'body':
            if (whitespace.test(ch))
                continue;
            string = string.substring(index);

            if (ch == '{')
                string = string.replace(/^{\s*(.*)\s*}\s*$/, '$1');
            else
                string = 'return ' + string.trim();

            index = string.length;
            break;

        default:
            throw '';
        }
    }

    return ['window.Function', args, string];
};
```

Comment: [I have made a much simpler version here](https://codepen.io/Hashbrown/pen/BPjLmy), but the tradeoff is that your function gets reconstructed for every call to the deserialised one. This *should* be negligible, so use this if you're not fond of the huge arguments parser above

Comment: I am trying to serialize this ƒ unsubscribeOne(i) { if (this.observers === undefined || this.observers[i] === undefined) { return; } delete this.observers[i]; this.observerCount -= 1… It's a function that is returned from calling this method https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged . However, I get the unexpected identifier error

Comment: @savram You are trying to serialise native browser code, that is, non-javascript, probably C++ code. [The unsub function is laundered through bind, you cannot get it.](https://i.imgur.com/811IU0G.png) Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

Don't serialize the call, instead try serializing the info, allowing to repeat the call, which can include things like class & method names, arguments passed into the call or just a call scenario name.

Answer (score -2):

```
w = (function(x){
    return function(y){ 
        return x+y; 
    };
});""+w returns "function(x){
    return function(y){
        return x+y;
    };
}" but ""+w(3) returns "function(y){
    return x+y; 
}"
```

which is not the same as w(3) which somehow still remembers to add 3.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.