# How to use third party js library in chrome extension using manifest 3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use `SheetJS` library in my chrome extension. My main code is present in `main.js`.

I am using `manifest_version:3`. I have used a function from `xlsx.full.min.js` to read excel file using the code present in `main.js`.

My `manifest.json` file is

```
"name":"My Extension",
"description":"About Extension",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version":3,

"icons": {
    "16":  "icon16.png",
    "48":  "icon48.png",
   "128": "icon128.png"
  },

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
      "run_at" : "document_end",
      "js": ["xlsx.full.min.js", "main.js"]
    }
  ]
```

After loading extension, `main.js` runs and shows the error `XLSX is not defined` meaning function defined in `xlsx.full.min.js` is not accessible to `main.js`.

Could anyone guide me how to make the functions in `xlsx.full.min.js` accessible to `main.js` ?

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you reloaded the extension in chrome://extensions and then reload the tab.

Answer (score 0):

My extension injects its code into the website and then it is run using a button. I later realised that this code does not run in the context of extension but in the context of website. So I passed the third party library code using `localStorage` to the injected code of the button and followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45676430/3009160 .