# A component has a useState() hook and its prop is an object with method. Why does using that method freeze the useState() hook?

Tags: javascript, deno, preact, freshjs

On `routes/index.tsx` I have:

```
import { PageProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";
import Test from "../islands/Test.tsx";

export default function App(prop: PageProps) {
  const a = {
    a: "a",
    b: function () {
      return "b";
    },
  };
  return (
    <body>
      <Test a={a} />
    </body>
  );
}
```

And on `islands/test.tsx` I have:

```tsx
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Test({ a }: any) {
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={keyword}
          onInput={(e) => setKeyword((e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value)}
        />
        <br />
        {keyword}
        {a.a}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This works. However, if I'm not using `{a.a}` but `{a.b()}`, then `useState()` stops working. Why is that? [The docs](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#usestate) doesn't say anything about this.

I put `console.log('handler')` in the input handler, and `console.log('function body')` in the function body. I got one `function body` when the server load, one `function body` when the client load, and none `handler` when I trigger the event.

I use Deno Fresh, which uses Preact. In Preact, [`onInput` is used instead of `onChange`](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/differences-to-react/#use-oninput-instead-of-onchange).

Comment: In React, you should use the `onChange` attribute, not `onInput`

Comment: In Preact, [`onInput` is the way to go](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/differences-to-react/#use-oninput-instead-of-onchange)

Comment: Why is this question bad?

Comment: because the problem isn't obvious or easily reproducible. Might even be a tooling issue.
Try putting a console.log in the input handler, see if it's even being called; and one in the function body to see when it's being re-rendered.

Comment: I got one `function body` when the server load, one `function body` when the client load, and none `handler` when I trigger the event.

Comment: This is a Fresh issue, nothing to do with Preact. In all likelihood, trying to pass a function across the island boundary is causing incorrect transforms, which makes sense, as functions cannot be serialized too easily.

Comment: I don't see what your `a` object and prop has to do with any React hook. So long as `a.b()` is synchronous and doesn't have any side-effects there should be no issue using it in the render return. Are you *sure* you have provided a complete [mcve]?

Comment: @rschristian why is that the case? From the question [How can I serialize a function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395686/3416774) I see that it's fairly easy, no?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, I don't know how to better reduce it more

Comment: Because calling `.toString()` and then executing with `new Function()` is incredibly dangerous.  You're executing arbitrary code at that point, code that comes across the network boundary and you have no way to ensure its authenticity.

Comment: @rschristian I see. So if I setup a secure environment then it should be fine? Would using HTTPS be enough?

Comment: I didn't ask to reduce it more, I'm asking if you need to provide *more* code in order to be considered a complete and reproducible example. In other words, perhaps you removed too much code and made too trivial an example to actually understand what you are trying to do and what the issue is with your actual code. Either way, this doesn't seem to be an issue with React hooks, but something with your environment and the way you are using Javascript.

Comment: HTTPS is very far from being enough, no, and "setup a secure environment" is easier said than done. There's a reason why CSP forbids `new Function()`. Additionally, this wouldn't work very well due to scoping issues. Anyways, this is fairly off topic and not super relevant. Passing a method like this as a prop is probably just not supported by Fresh, likely for good reasons.

Comment: @rschristian I agree that this is off-topic; briefly explaining about HTTPS is enough for me. If you make that an answer I'll accept it